# WooCommerce callback not catching POST data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to send data via POST method to a WooCommerce callback but when I tested by using `var_dump` it return an empty array : `array(0) { }`

Can any one help me figure it out?

```
function check_ipn_response()
    {
        global $woocommerce;
        var_dump( $_POST);


            if (isset($_POST["payment_status"]) && isset($_POST["hash"]))
            {
             }
            else
            {
                wp_die(' Erreur de notification de paiement');
            }

    }
```

Comment: You probably need to add the function to a wordpress / woocommerce action hook:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference / https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/index.html $_POST gets cleared by wp at some point.

Comment: It's added 
add_action('woocommerce_api_wc_' . $this->id, array($this, 'check_ipn_response'));

Comment: I assume WP already cleared the $_POST by then. Can you try and set it to 'init'? As the WP docs state `Use init to act on $_POST data`

Comment: Please specify how you are sending the POST data. Are you trying to handle a PayPal request?

Comment: i am sending it by result=wp_remote_post() , it's look like not sending any data because when i wrote echo 'something'; and i checked by var_dump(result) i got nothing

Comment: For debugging please try sending the HTTP request using curl or using the browser (in which case you need to change $_POST to $_GET). Can you include the code that calls wp_remote_post. Is this for handling a PayPal IPN request?

Comment: wp_remote_post() using curl already..and no it's not for  handling a PayPal IPN request it's for handling my own payment soltuion IPN request

Comment: I am referring to the command line curl - this will allow you to replace the sending side with something that is known to work. If the problem is in the sending side then it would be useful if you included the code that calls wp_remote_post().

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress cleares the $_POST variable after it is done with handling the request. So the hook we need to use has to be before that. The [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) state:

> init is useful for intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.

So the action we need should be

```
add_action('init', 'check_ipn_response');
```

Comment: "Wordpress cleares the $_POST variable after it is done with handling the request." - Please give a reference to code or documentation for this. I was not aware of this and would like to learn more.

Comment: I'm not sure as wordpress is not very clear about this, but i've ran into it a couple of times myself.

Comment: Do you recall the circumstances? I have used the $_POST variable often in many,many different actions and filters and it has always been available. It seems wrong to me that WordPress would clear this essential variable - I don't know for sure which is why I am asking.